# PIC12LF1552 I2C; uC won't exit Start Condition

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, microchip, xc8

So I've been tackling this problem with integrating I2C functionality into my code, which is documented here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224541/receiving-undefined-symbols-error-with-xc8-concerning-plib-i2c-functions

**TLDR: I2C plib didn't work because PIC12 is not a PIC18, I sorted it out by copying the sources and changing the relevant regs, hoping that it would work...**

...and now I've run into another stumbling block. When the program tries to open an I2C connection, it seemingly remains stuck on the `StartI2C()` method which sets `SSPCON2bits.SEN` high and as it is so commented in the copied sources waits for it to "automatically be cleared by hardware". I'm running this in MPLABX's simulator and this is where its stuck, I have a PICkit3, but it tells me it can't breakpoint anywhere, so thats useless for actually debugging the part, so I'm assuming whats happening in the simulator is exactly whats happening on the part (which is a poor assumption, but I've got nothing else to really rely on right now).

So I'm guessing theres two questions here, **should the ported code be compatible as written since it was written for the MSSP module that is probably copied around in many of their parts?**

and

**If the `SSPCON2bits.SEN` bit is supposed to be cleared by hardware automatically, why isn't it being cleared?**

All of the relevant code concerning my wrappers and setup are in the linked StackOverflow question. All the relevant code concerning Microchip's I2C plib drivers are located in any install of MPLABX with XC8 under `/path/to/xc8/install/directory/version/sources/pic18/plib/i2c/i2c_*.c` with the header file being inside `/path/to/xc8/install/directory/version/include/plib/i2c.h`.

**UPDATE: All the code**

- **i2c.h - Microchip code modified for PIC12LF1552**

  - pastebin.com/wLUJ0xpH
- **i2c.c - Microchip code modified for PIC12LF1552**

  - pastebin.com/CTEyZETf
- **plur_i2c.h - My header file for wrapping Microchip's I2C functions**

  - pastebin.com/HvphrFC8
- **plur_i2c.c - My source file for wrapping Microchip's I2C functions**

  - pastebin.com/F95Kjrzj
- **main.c - Main body of code to be executed (not complete)**

  - pastebin.com/NyTkP2pU

Answer (score 1):

You should not assume that the simulator mimics real hardware exactly, however in this case it may be failing for a similar reason. If SCL or SDA are low during start then a bus collision is assumed, the start is aborted, BCLIF flag is set (which generates an interrupt if enabled) and the MSSP module is reset. If the I<sup>2</sup>C bus is in a permanent collision state and your program continuously retries then it may appear to be  'stuck' at that point.

SCL and SDA are normally held high with pullup resistors. In the simulator, what is the normal state of the SCL and SDA pins? On your actual hardware, have you checked that your pullups are on the correct pins? What voltages are present? Have you monitored the pins with an oscilloscope or logic analyzer?

Another possibility is that your modified header files are still not compatible, and the MSSP is not being correctly initialized. You could examine all the relevant hardware registers in the simulator to verify that they have the correct values, or post your code here for others to try out.

Comment: The SCL and SDA pins a pulled-up to the system reference voltage (3.3 -> 5V depending on whats powering it, i.e: PICkit, battery, or USB) with two 1.5kOhm resistors. The voltage present on the bus is as you would expect, the system reference voltage. I have hooked up a scope to the pins and didn't see any activity, but given whats going on in the simulator and again (poorly) assuming that the exact same thing is happening on the part, it tries to send a START condition, but is hanging at waiting for the `SSPCON2bits.SEN` to become unset. I'll update the question with the relevant code.

Comment: The relevant code has been uploaded to pastebin and appended to the OP.

Comment: I don't have a logic analyzer, but I just ordered a Saleae Logic to help verify the transactions better.

Comment: Pastebin says the the file 'plur_i2c.h' has been removed. :(

Comment: You are assigning SDA to pin 4 (RA3) with APFCONbits.SDSEL = 1, but in CONFIG you have MCLRE_ON which assigns pin 4 to MCLR. If you have SDA connected to pin 4 then you need to change the config to MCLRE_OFF. If you are using pin 5 (RA2) for SDA then you need to set APFCONbits.SDSEL=0.

Comment: Ahh, I'll reupload it and change the post again, but really plur_i2c.h just contains prototypes for plur_i2c.c and `#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0b11110000` as well as including the modified Microchip header.

Comment: Changed `MCLRE_ON -> MCLRE_OFF`, still observing the same result inside the simulator, the part also doesn't move, but still waiting on that logic analyzer to confirm that.

Comment: The simulator doesn't support I2C on the 12LF1552, so of course it won't start. However you can still check whether the SFR's are being correctly initialized. I see that you are not loading a baud rate into SSP1ADD. The minimum value supported is 3, so I2C might not work with its power-on value of 0. With your 500KHz Fosc the maximum I2C frequency you can have is 31.25KHz. If you need a higher I2C frequency then you will have to select a higher Fosc.

Comment: Okay, so i set a baud rate of 400KHz, setting `__XTAL_FREQ 16000000` and set SSPADD to 39, no change in the system was observed.

Comment: RA1 (SCL) defaults to analog input. Try setting it to digital mode with ANSELAbits.ANSA1 = 0;

Comment: Still no dice, in fact, now the part doesn't operate under the simpler working program (without i2c) even though the programmer says it's been successfully programmed.

Comment: Go back to basics: first get it to flash a LED, then add your I2C stuff etc. Unfortunately I don't have a 12LF1552 on hand, but I tested your code (with the mods discussed) on a 16F1824, and it worked fine once I enabled digital input on SCL. http://pastebin.com/5uT5XdnA http://pastebin.com/XD3usAEK

Comment: So I've gotten it to blink again... but theres now another issue, I have this loop as a basic program `while(1) { LATAbits.LATA4 = !LATAbits.LATA4; __delay_ms(100); }`, and it programs and works, but unless 100ms == 2-3s, then somethings seriously wrong here...

Comment: Okay resolved the delay issue by shifting the delays to `__delay_us(someamount);` but the timing absolutely does not match the input value.

Comment: Alright, now I've made every single mod suggested and I don't see transactions going over the bus or the LED light indicating that the uC has even processed through the method.

Comment: In further debugging, I've put LED toggles throughout the code, I can reach into my `Connect();` method and the LED toggles, I put a toggle at the top of `OpenI2C();` and the LED doesn't toggle...

Comment: If __delay_ms() is giving the wrong timing then you probably haven't set up the system clock correctly. Try temporarily enabling CLKOUT and measure the frequency on pin 3. Once you have the correct clock timing, try blinking a LED on RA1.